# biases in deriving a feature(x1) from Target variable(y) and using x1 as a predictor

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, mathematical-statistics, predictive-models, bias

We are developing a student employability model which predicts the employment of given student after he completes his MS degree. We are primarily using logistic regression. I have a query regarding our modeling approach and need some advice.

***Query   -***

I am trying to derive a feature(x1) from Target variable(y) and using x1 as a predictor in the training data.
          What are the challenges and biases I might encounter in the estimates / predictive model while using this approach?

***Additional context regarding the query -***

As of now, (from the data) we know Indian College rank, US college Rank, branch, Year of experience are significant in predicting employability of student.

One of our hypotheses is that in the USA, the specific college can affect the employment, because of its location, brand name, alums etc.. Therefore, we have calculated college-level average unemployment from our own data and added it as a feature in our training data.

***Concern -***

Intuitively, the approach seems alright, but we are not sure whether it is advisable from a theoretical viewpoint. We are concerned that this may lead to biased estimates.